# Belkin N600 USB Wireless adapter on Ubuntu 14.10 problem?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, 14.10

Brand new to Ubuntu (although I have upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04) and I am still reading the 'books' on how to work with Linux.

I am switching from a land line to wireless internet and my tower computer doesn't have a wi-fi adapter built in, so I bought a Belkin N300 adapter. (the crazy thing says N600 on the actual adapter though, so I am confused already) and the model number is F91101v2 and so far Ask Ubuntu and Wiki have no articles listing how to install or connect to the internet using this adapter AND Ubuntu 14.10.

I saw

- [Belkin N600 USB Wireless adapter on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394159/belkin-n600-usb-wireless-adapter-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [How can I get a Belkin N600 DB (F9L1101v1) to work on Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190791/how-can-i-get-a-belkin-n600-db-f9l1101v1-to-work-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

But I was not able to get the suggestions there to work.

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 03f0:2504 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet F4200 series
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 045e:00d1 Microsoft Corp. Optical Mouse with Tilt Wheel
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

What can I do?

Comment: There's books?  There is a script available on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/283721) which gathers all of the information required to assist in determining your problems.  Please run the script and past the results at [ubuntu pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your device from the terminal: lsusb. I think it may be: 050d:615a. If so, please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/394159/belkin-n600-usb-wireless-adapter-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: chili555> this is what I got from the lsusb:Bus 002 Device 006: ID 03f0:2504 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet F4200 series
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 045e:00d1 Microsoft Corp. Optical Mouse with Tilt Wheel
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Also, I did try the question from 12.04 link and it didn't work for me. there was an error message for the ndiswrapper as well

Comment: Charles Green - did as you asked and did the 'paste bin' link' sure hope you all can figure out what I am doing wrong. and yeah, I bought some of the books on ubuntu and linux that are on Kindle. they did help me figure out how to change to my directory and desktop file but had nothing about how to get or install drivers this way.

Comment: @MichealRainwater Yours is a different device from the device in the ndiswrapper link. See my answer below.

Comment: Got to the ((git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git)) and recieved the message:  >>could not create work tree dir 'rtl8192du' .: Permission denied.  doh-i added 'sudo' to the second command.line.and.now.ot.is.downloading.

Comment: IDid the ((cd)) and typed in 'make'. now i have:  make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build M=/rtl8192du modules.    make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-37--generic/build M=rtl8192du modules.      make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build: Stop.   Makefile:149: recipe for target. 'modules' failed.     make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: @chili555 can you read the other posts in this thread?

Comment: @MichealRainwater Did you copy and paste my commands exactly? It works for me. Try sudo make.

Comment: Will try 'sudo make' again - i am trired and confused but willing to keep tryong

Answer (score 1):

Based on your device ID; Device 006: ID **050d:110a** Belkin Components, it is driven by the relatively new driver 8192du.  Please get a working internet connection and copy and paste these commands, each one at a time.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git
cd rtl8192du
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

You probably also need to load the firmware:

```
sudo cp ~/rtl8192du/rtl8192dufw*  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
sudo depmod -a
```

It may take a reboot. Your wireless should now be working. Please let us know as we will have one additional step.

Comment: Nope - it's not working!

Comment: @MichealRainwater Please see my edit above.

Comment: Posted a reply to @charles green's answer instead of yours can you see them or do i need to repost?

Comment: I see them. See my response above.

Comment: I got through this set until i did the (cd rtl8192du command).  Then i entered the 'make' command.     The result i got was:      make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C/lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build M=/rtl8192du modules

Comment: That was followed by:   make [1]: 149: receipe for target 'modules' failed.   make: *** [modules]  Error 2

Comment: Something is terribly wrong. Did you start in your home directory? cd ~ and then git should work without sudo. Are you sure you installed the prerequisites as in the first command?

Comment: Yes i was in my home directory. it says that git is the newest and the generics are up to date. when i tried to do the 'sudo cp' thing it tells me: cp: cannot stat '/home/(my id/logon)/rtl8192du/rtl8192dufw*': No such file or directory

Comment: Also : to the.Admin folks - i WOULD go to chat but i'm so new to Ubuntu that you wont.let me. Sorry

Comment: Sorry Admin guys:  I tried to follow. the link and 'move this discussion to chat' but your link sai i'm too new to go there.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you had wired internet before, but when you got this wireless adapter, did you get a wireless router with it as well? If you know the name of your wireless network and the security key (if it applies), do you see an icon in the upper right that appears as a pie shape (that's the best way I can describe it)? That would be the wireless icon. If you click there, does the card list any networks around you at all? That'd be a good starting point, and indicate you at least have some type of connection with the USB stick, and that'd give us a step in the right direction.

I found some information that may be useful... I wouldn't consider it very user-friendly, but try the following, and let me know if it at least works for you.

I downloaded the driver package from [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=2&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8192SU). Belkin doesn't make their own chip on the inside of that USB stick, but the actual chip is a Realtek RTL8192SU-GR. You'll see where it says Unix/Linux, download from one of the mirror links. The next thing you'll want to do is to extract it anywhere, perhaps the desktop, just so you can get to the folder. Next, open a terminal, and get to where that file is. There is an install script, but you'll have to make it run. At the command prompt, type in:

> $ sudo -i
>
> $ cd ~/desktop/ (where  is that folder you saved to the
>   desktop)
>
> $ chmod 775 install.sh
>
> $ sudo ./install.sh

It should follow the script and install itself, similar to how some things have to be installed in Windows. It should work I believe, from what I see here at least.

Let me know if you are still struggling.

Comment: Okay - maybe if i can retype the info,with no typos, you will be able to help.

Comment: i did the 'cd rtl8192du' and got to the directory.  Then i entered the 'make' command; this is. the result i got: >make ARCH=386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C/lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build: Stop.    Makefile [1]: 149: receipe for target 'modules' failed.  make: *** [modules] Error 2