# How can I install the driver for Belkin N600 wireless adapter on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

I have read through questions concerning installing driver for this wireless adapter, and found that the driver is closely dependent on the details of each adapter, thus I post my adapter here and ask for specific instructions. If further information is needed, please let me know, thanks!

I just followed the answer provided by Ben Lee in [How can I get a Belkin N600 DB (F9L1101v1) to work on Ubuntu 12,04 64-Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190791/how-can-i-get-a-belkin-n600-db-f9l1101v1-to-work-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit) to try installing the driver. Every step is successfully done except for the last step, where I enhanced it with `sudo modprobe 8192du`. I then restarted the computer, but it seems it does not work. Even the light on the Belkin adapter is not turned on (in Windows, the light labelled with ((|)) will be on to show that it is at least working). Thanks for further help!

`lsusb` gives the following information,

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 050d:615a Belkin Components F7D4101 / F9L1101 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM4323]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: try `rfkill unblock all`

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried, but no change in the adapter.

Comment: why did you `sudo modprobe 8192du`? Does `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` not work for you?

Comment: The Realtek driver 8192du is incorrect for your Broadcom BCM4323 device. Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/394159/belkin-n600-usb-wireless-adapter-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

It seems we must use ndiswrapper to install the driver. The answer provided by Ben Lee in [How can I get a Belkin N600 DB (F9L1101v1) to work on Ubuntu 12,04 64-Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190791/how-can-i-get-a-belkin-n600-db-f9l1101v1-to-work-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit) does not work for my case.